# How to add Author image and description - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, author

I am new to php.

I use author image widget.
http://www.semiologic.com/software/author-image/

I use the following simple code to get the author image.

author.php:
`$auth_foto = the_author_image($authorid);
echo $auth_foto;`

it's working fine. its showing the author image.

Now I want to show the author description and his posts title below the image?
How can I do that?

I've tried `<?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?>`
but it's not working.

Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION**
it's working fine now when I using the following code.

```
`
$author_id=$post->post_author;

$auth_foto = the_author_image($author_id);

function auth_desc ($author_id) { 
echo the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id).'<br/>'; 
echo get_the_author_meta('user_email', $author_id).'<br/>';                 
echo the_author_meta( 'description', $author_id).'<br/>'.'<br/>'.'<br/>'; 
}  

echo $auth_foto; auth_desc($author_id); `
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this tag work with ID like :

```
<?php the_author_meta( $field, $userID ); ?>
```

Details [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_author_meta)

according to your code you can try like this :

```
<?php $auth_foto = the_author_image($authorid);
$userId = 1;
function auth_desc ($userId) { 
    echo get_the_author_meta('user_email', $userId); 
    echo the_author_meta('display_name', $userId);
 echo the_author_meta( 'description', $userId); } 
 echo $auth_foto; auth_desc($userId); ?>
```

In the above code assign dynamic value to `$userID`.

Comment: Thanks for that..
I've had a look at that..
the problem is the following code not printing the authors detail..
but it's printing the author image..
` 
   <?php 
   
   $auth_foto = the_author_image($authorid);
   $auth_detail = the_author_meta( 'description', $authorid );
   echo $auth_foto;
   echo $auth_detail;
     
   ?>
  `
any idea?

Comment: this method send output directly to browser.you can't assign it to variable like you did.Try like this  <?php the_author_meta('user_email',25); ?><

Comment: thanks for that..
now the following code working..
`<?php    
   $auth_foto = the_author_image($authorid);
   function auth_desc () {
   echo get_the_author_meta('user_email', 1);
   echo the_author_meta('display_name', 1);
   echo the_author_meta( 'description', 1);
   }
   echo $auth_foto;
   auth_desc();
   ?>`
but I have 2 authors.. those detail should be shown automatically under their pages. so that Author ID must be assigned automatically.. doesn't that?
but now all the detail belong to user id 1.
so how can I change it assign that author or user ID automatically?

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.. it's echoing what I want..
But also showing a warning..
`Warning: Missing argument 1 for auth_desc(), called in /home/host3003/public_html/blog/wp-content/themes/3003Blog-1/author.php on line 27 and defined in /home/host3003/public_html/blog/wp-content/themes/3003Blog-1/author.php on line 20 - See more at: http://www.3003online.com/blog/author/3003admin/#sthash.gHCyMSaY.dpuf'
how can we correct it?

Comment: it's working like a charm sir..
sorry for the wrong comment above.
thanks a lot..
can u bit explain me those codes..?
why we are assigning 1 to $UserID?

Comment: @NewbieStarr If the user ID fields is used, then this function display the specific field for that user ID.Its  Default value is false.you can read more about the function on google.Also accept the answer if this help you.

Comment: it's always echoing the author who's ID is 1.
it does not echoing the author 1 even the author ID of the post is 2.
then I;ve changed the code like following and its working fine now.
it's showing the proper author's details.
`$author_id=$post->post_author;  
$auth_foto = the_author_image($author_id);
function auth_desc ($author_id) { 
echo the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id).'<br/>'; 
echo get_the_author_meta('user_email', $author_id).'<br/>';     
echo the_author_meta( 'description', $author_id).'<br/>'.'<br/>'.'<br/>'; 
}  
echo $auth_foto; auth_desc($author_id); `

Answer (score 1):

If you use the function outside of The Loop you need to add the author id.

```
<?php the_author_meta( 'description', $authorid ); ?>
```

Side note: some themes (especially the default themes) automatically show author name, picture and description when the blog has more than one user.

Comment: thank for that..
i've tried that..
but not working..
`<?php 
   
   $auth_foto = the_author_image($authorid);
   $auth_detail = the_author_meta( 'description', $authorid );
   echo $auth_foto;
   echo $auth_detail;
     
   ?>`
it's not printing $auth_detail;
any suggestions?

Comment: `the_author_meta()` does not return anything, it directly outputs the content. If you want to store the description for later use you have to use `get_the_author_meta()` (usage is the same). Depending on where you call `the_author_meta()` the output might be suppressed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation..
I am not sure I am using the right code because of my PHP knowledge.
`<?php 
   
   $auth_foto = the_author_image($authorid);
   $auth_detail = get_the_author_meta( 'description', $authorid );
   echo $auth_foto;
   echo $auth_detail;
     
   ?>`
still the $$auth_detail; not be printed

is that correct code?